# Strange behaviour of Assert.assertEquals

Tags: java, junit

According to many posts here, `Assert.assertEquals` should compare collections using deep insight, and two arrays of the same content should be equal.

I have JUnit 4.12 installed.

Calling

```
List<Integer[]> result, targetResult;
(both are created as ArrayList)
....
Assert.assertEquals("counted small array ", result, targetResult);
```

, where result and targetResult have the same content, the test fails though.

I have looked how the `assertEquals` do the job. For comparison of the Integer arrays it reached:

```
//----in AbstractList: 
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof List))
        return false;

    ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
    ListIterator e2 = ((List) o).listIterator();
    while (e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) {
        E o1 = e1.next();
        Object o2 = e2.next();
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
    ...

//and more deep, in Object:
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

And that means, that it compares simply references.

How can I make `Assert.assertEquals()` to work correctly?

Comment: I wonder where the confusion is. `Assert.assertEquals` obviously calls `#equals` on one of the passed arguments and this will work for collections, since they override this method, but won't work for arrays. And it doesn't matter if one passes arrays to `Assert.assertEquals` or wrapped in collections, since these arrays still don't override `#equals`.

Comment: @Tom Oh. So, the Assert.assertEquals simply does NOT works on List<Anything[]>. Thank you and please make an answer out of this comment - it is the answer I need... I see that it works so, but so many people told the other way that I thought maybe I have some defective JUnit...

Comment: `Assert.assertEquals` does always the same: calling `#equals` and the collections also just call `#equals` of the collected objects, so you end up using the `#equals` method of `Anything[]` and no arrays does override `#equals`, therefore it doesn't actually compare the content of the array. That is way where are "workaround method" which compare the actual array content, like [`Arrays.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28boolean[],%20boolean[]%29)

Comment: @Tom I see and I agree. Why don't you make an answer?

Comment: Because Peter already wrote a good answer :D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with assertEquals is the assumption that the `equals(Object)` is sane. Unfortunately, all arrays inherent from Object directly and have no specialised methods.  This means that you have to call Arrays.equals(a, b) to compare two arrays, however if those arrays are inside a collection there is no way to do this conveniently.

Note: I don't know why printing `[Ljava.lang.Integer@72173fed` is a good `toString` for such an array either (it is something I have ranted against in my blog more than once)

> And that means, that it compares simply hashcodes.

It doesn't compare hashCode()s, it compares references.  hashCode()s are not memory addresses, nor can they be as they cannot change when the object is moved in memory.

If you want your data structures to be equal, use a collection which supports equals as you expect

```
List<List<Integer>> result
```

if you you want efficiency as `int` use 4 bytes and `Integer` can use 20 bytes including it's reference.

```
List<int[]> result

public static void assertEqualsArray(List<Int[]> a, List<int[]> b) {
   // compare the list of arrays.
}
```

Comment: 1. Thank you, I have already written my method that does the work. But I wanted to understand what is the problem with Assert.assertEquals().  2. I was remembering that List[int] is impossible. It is something new, isn't it? 3. Of course, references. I am a bit drown in hashcodes. Corrected.

Comment: @Gangnus 1. assertEquals assumes the .equals(Object) method is sane. 2. List<int> might be possible in Java 10. 3. Confusing hashCode with memory addresses is common, even if you read the Javadoc for this method o_O

Comment: I meant the List<int[]>, sorry. I thought, it is forbidden, too.

Comment: So, Integer[].equals() is not the sane. Alas.

Comment: @Gangnus all the arrays inherit from Object and have no specialization of their own (except a final field called `length`) This has been a cause for WTF moments from a long time but it seems fixing it is not easy for reasons I don't entirely understand.  In the meantime you need to use `List` or customize handling. Like `Arrays`, `Array` `ArrayUtil`, `ArrayUtils` and so many other utility classes.

Comment: Thank you. I hope I see the picture better now.

Comment: Could you put that info on Assert.assertEquals() and array equality into the answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(result.toArray(), targetResult.toArray());
```